# Large result sets with Oracle JDBC, can I turn cursor fetching off? (fetch size issue)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a case where i need to efficiently load about ~1 million rows into memory for processing. I am using oracle and plain JDBC for this.

If I do not set the fetch size, the oracle driver default of 10 is used meaning it will require 100k round trips which makes performance super inefficient. If I up the fetch size to something very large, such as 500k or 1m, the data is loaded in about 5 seconds.

Unfortunately I can't set the fetch size to something like INT_MAX because the oracle driver pre-allocates the buffer based on the fetch size.

What I really want is a way to force JDBC to simply get all of the rows and not use a cursor or do any incremental fetching. I would like to do that in the most memory efficient way possible.

Is there a way to tell oracle to just get all the data and don't do any fetching?

Comment: This is probably a bad idea.  You're not the first to erroneously think that they need to bring a huge record set to the server side, process it, and put it back.  Consider either committing smaller chunk sizes or processing on the database server itself.

Comment: I would definitely recommend trying to do the processing in the database.

Comment: In my experience setting the fetch size substantially bigger then e.g. 10000 doesn't really improve performance. I doubt that if you go beyond your 500k you will notice any substantial performance improvement (does it get any faster then 5 seconds with say 2 million?). And don't forget that you would keep the result set in memory **twice** (the driver and your application)

Comment: doing processing in the database isn't going to help here. I'm implementing an internal web service for the bulk download of this data.

Comment: I would like to avoid playing the game of figuring out optimal fetch sizes for every query. I classify queries in 2 categories: those that can fit entirely in memory and those that cant. For the latter category fetch sizes are perfect. But most of my queries are in the first category. I would like for a way to tell oracle to just fetch all of the rows without making any unnecessary round trips.

Answer (score 1):

The 12 driver allocates 15 bytes per column per row in the fetch size for bookkeeping plus the actual data size. So if you set the fetch size to 1G the 12 driver will allocate 15GB for bookkeeping plus whatever the actual data is. So depending on how much memory you have you can set the fetch size to whatever you have the memory to support.

Pre 12 the drivers allocated much, much more memory so the fetch size would have to be much smaller.

There's no way to tell the driver to just fetch all the rows in one round trip.

Edit 2017-03-10: We have tested with up to 2G rows and the recently released 12.2 drivers handle this fine with a FORWARD_ONLY result set. They will handle up to 1,802,723,000 rows with a SCROLL_INSENSITIVE result set. That is an expected limit. Sort of obviously this is with a huge machine and a ginormous heap.