# oracle sql query limit

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have to read data in batches and I want to know what is the limit of an sql-query and is there any limit in JDBC driver as well for max-sql-query size. I am using oracle 19c database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum statement length in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355819/what-is-the-maximum-statement-length-in-oracle)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981742/large-result-sets-with-oracle-jdbc-can-i-turn-cursor-fetching-off-fetch-size/42015477#42015477) may help.